# How to think about magnetic wells?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, magnetic-fields

From classical mechanics we have the basic credo that a system chooses to minimize its energy. Since the energy is given by $$ E = T + V $$ where $T$ is the kinetic energy (usually $T=P^2$ for non-relativistic particles) is positive, and $V$ is the potential energy (just a function from space to $\mathbb{R}$), we have a very intuitive picture:

The system seeks to spend as much time as possible at the minima of $V$, and these points are of special importance.

This intuition, crucially, carries over to quantum mechanics as well, since then $P^2$ is a positive operator.

What is the analog of this when one has also a magnetic field? (for simplicity let us take even $V=0$). We know we have (classically or quantum mechanically) $$ E = (P-A)^2 = P^2-A\cdot P -P \cdot A+A^2 $$ where $A$ is the magnetic vector potential. Now since we do not have two positive terms it is not so clear anymore how the shape of $A:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$ determines where the system wants to be (and anyway the answer should only depend on $\mathrm{curl}(A)\equiv B$).

At least for constant magnetic fields we know particles like to be in cyclotron orbits. But what if $A$ has arbitrary form? Can one think of building a trapping potential out of choosing a particular type of $A$?

I'm sure this is very basic physics but somehow I've never played with it. Can anyone point to what kind of physics purely magnetic wells are useful in, and how to best think about them?

Comment: Magnetic trapping is performed by adding a quadrupole, non-uniform magnetic field to the red-shifted laser beams used for cooling. This field is zero at the center of the trap and increases in intensity with the distance from the center  By Zeeman effect, its addition produces a subdivision of the (hyperfine) energy levels used for the transition, according to the different values ​​of the magnetic quantum number mF, the difference between the levels thus separated increasing with the radial distance to the center of the trap . https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magneto-optical_trap

Answer (score 0):

One has to be careful here because the ordinary definition of a well does not apply to a charged particle in an arbitrary static magnetic field. This is because the force is always perpendicular to the velocity of the particle and is not anti-parallel to either the velocity or displacement like you would have in the common understanding of a well (i.e. something like a harmonic oscillator). So the best that can be hoped for is to trap the particle in a confined (quasi)cyclical orbit. But because the length scale of that orbit grows with smaller speeds (i.e. centripetal acceleration goes as $v\times B$), the well will only trap particles with specific speeds/angles in general, as the orbits of the lowest energy particles will exceed the apparatus. This issue is the case with the magnetic bottle/mirror (see note below*), where you can only temporarily trap particles for 10s of milliseconds. Such a setup isn't a *well* per se because it only works for specific angles and velocities, whereas the "usual" meaning of a well is a stable equilibrium point due to an energy barrier.

In terms of trapping magnetic dipoles, [Earnshaw's theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earnshaw%27s_theorem) extends to magnetostatic potentials in that case, so a static magnetic setup does not work in general. See [here](https://web.physics.ucsb.edu/%7Electuredemonstrations/Composer/Pages/68.78.html) and [here](https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/General/Levitation/levitation.html) for more discussions on Earnshaw's theorem in the context of magnetism.

The essential point is that the magnetic field in free space also obeys the Laplace equation $\nabla^2B=0$ resulting in many of the same restrictions as the electric field.

One has to include other effects to get trapping with a magnetic field in practice, such as:

1. Some use of the [Zeeman interaction](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeeman_effect) $\mu \cdot B$. Optical dipole traps with lasers, such as the [magneto-optical trap](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magneto-optical_trap) (MOT) combine Zeeman splitting gradients with optical traps. Another example for *pre-cooled* particles is the magnetic gradient trap, which notably is very shallow and requires some pre-cooling with *another trap* beforehand to work.
2. Using *diamagnetic* materials in a magnetic gradient
3. Time-varying magnetic fields, e.g. a maglev train setup where the field switches based on the magnets position to keep it levitating.
4. Use *both* magnetostatic and electrostatic fields ([Penning trap](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penning_trap))

*u/Axensen brought up the magnetic mirror trap. This scheme uses a magnetic field distribution where the particle bounces back and forth in a bottle-like magnetic field. This a valid *temporary* trap in the literal sense, but it requires a particular condition on the velocity for particles to stay trapped. So this method is an inherently temporary trap until the particle loses some energy and/or thermalizes with its surrounding. This scheme is different from the usual concept of a well where the stabilized particle should live indefinitely until some external effect knocks it out.

Comment: Your list of other effects seems to miss magnetic mirrors, which can trap charged particles: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_mirror and magnetic minimum traps for atoms with a magnetic moment: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_trap_(atoms). I guess you could argue this is a kind of "diamagnetic" effect, but that would be a pretty big stretch IMO.

Comment: Good points, I've appended the list. For the mirror, that does only trap within a select speed and trajectory band, which made me hesitate to add it. If you had a particle with near zero speed it would not stay in that trap, which makes it different that what normally is imagined for a trap

Comment: small nitpick on that comment - the trapping condition for a magnetic mirror is the ratio of the velocity parallel vs perpendicular to the magnetic field. So a particle can have arbitrarily low total speed, but still be trapped provided that when it's in the center of the trap, a sufficient ratio of its speed is in the perpendicular direction.

Comment: @AXensen also good point! I tried to write up my thoughts above. I have never used those traps, but I assume that it isn't really feasible to go to very low speeds where you don't have precise enough control of that ratio? At least getting a particular ratio for neutral atoms or ions would require a specialized cooling setup because inevitable heating would scramble that ratio

Answer (score 0):

Mathematically, the analogue of the  harmonic oscillator for the magnetic case is a uniform magnetic field. Indeed, the resulting Hamiltonian is quadratic in phase space, and the equations of motion are linear. Conversely, the most general quadratic Hamiltonian with a magnetic field corresponds to a uniform magnetic field. Similarly, a small velocity localizes the particle at a given place ie the motions’s amplitude vanishes with velocity. However, there is no privileged position for this localization which can happen anywhere, whereas for the harmonic oscillator it can only happen at the origin.

In general, the study of mechanic energy is not sufficient to build intuition for dynamics in a magnetic field. Standard surrogates are [adiabatic invariants](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adiabatic_invariant). A nice introduction is given in *Mathematical Understanding of Nature* by VI Arnold using the most commonly used one: $v_\perp^2$.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What is an "electronic harmonic oscillator"? Laplace's equation in free space doesn't let you create a harmonic potential in 3D (only saddle points) which is the magnetic field example does not confine parallel to $B$ in your example

Comment: This answer has some useful ideas but it isn't entirely clear to me. You can make a harmonic oscillator in one or two dimensions, but not all three - you cannot trap a charged particle in all three dimensions using free-space electrostatics. Likewise, while it's interesting that a constant magnetic field similarly localizes a particle in two dimensions, it doesn't trap the particle in the third dimension. Finally, these two sentences seem contradictory or I'm not understanding something... "A small velocity localizes the particle at a given place. However, there is no spatial localization."

Answer (score 0):

As other people here have noted, a magnetic "well" is pretty complicated; you need a quadrupole term in the magnetic field, which is more difficult to analyze than a mere magnetic field gradient.

But if you think about it, any generic "well" is just a number of force gradients all coming together, so it's far more illuminating to start with just a simple case of a magnetic field with a constant spatial gradient, something like $B = ax \hat{z}$.  This describes a $\hat{z}$-directed magnetic field that linearly grows in magnitude as you travel in the x-direction.  (I'm assuming the constant $a$ is positive.)

Such a magnetic field will cause a drift velocity to any Larmor-orbits of charged particles orbiting around the B-field in the x-y plane (see the first 1-2 chapters of any [plasma physics textbook](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-22309-4)), because now the force isn't constant as it orbits.  The circles turn into cycloids – the radius gets larger on the $-x$ side and smaller on the $+x$ side.  It's not hard to see that in this case the net "drift force" will be in the y-direction for a positively charged particle.  [In general](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guiding_center#Grad-B_drift), the drift for positive charges is in the $\vec{B} \times \nabla |B|$ direction.

Now, your question gets at the interesting point of how to think about this drift from a vector-potential perspective.  In the Coloumb gauge, the vector potential which corresponds to the above field is $\vec{A} = ax^2 \hat{y}$, always pointing in the y-direction – the very same direction of the drift!  This is not a coincidence.

You've already done most of the work in your question, noting that you end up with a crucial term $-\vec{p} \cdot \vec{A}$.  That term will tend to push the particle in the $A$ direction, on average.  In fact, since the actual particle is orbiting around the field, constantly changing its direction, the "averaging" procedure is a lot more physical in this case than it is in a typical single-particle mechanics problem; the particle is sampling more of its phase space.

I like the idea of using this general idea to build a trapping potential in the vector-potential viewpoint, and then figuring out what magnetic field it might correspond to.  I don't know if that's been looked at -- but of course arbitrary magnetic field geometries can be quite hard to create in the first place.

Comment: In free space, you should be able to write the B field as arising from a scalar potential. That makes Earnshaw's theorem apply and forbid magnetic traps with a few caveats

Comment: @KFGauss That comment seems to imply that when there is a scalar potential for the magnetic field, that scalar potential is the potential energy. If there was a particle for which $V=q\Phi_B$ ($\Phi_B$ is the magnetic scalar potential, $V$ is the _potential energy_), then Earnshaw's theorem would say that this particle cannot be trapped in free space. But nothing interacts with the magnetic field that way, and in fact the way a magnetic field changes the charged particle Lagrangian is not by changing the potential, but by changing the conjugate momentum of position.

Comment: @AXensen yes I thought about it and I think my comment is incorrect. Thanks for pointing it out